# return a prop inside useEffect ()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am newbie to react hooks I al trying to return a prop value from parent inside my useEffect hook:

Here is me code with hardcoded value

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function LinearDeterminate(props) {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProgress(() => {
      return props.goalPercentage;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Instead of 50 I would like to return a value from parent component : props.goalPercentage

Here I am getting a warning :

```
 Line 13:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 
'props.goalPercentage'. Either include it or remove the dependency 
 array. If 'setProgress' needs the current value of 
'props.goalPercentage', you can also switch to useReducer instead of 
 useState and read 'props.goalPercentage' in the reducer  react- 
 hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Plus the react console is showing the value of progress ad undefined :

props

```
value : undefined
variant: determinate"
```

Here is the return of the parent :

```
return (
    <div>
      <Card
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.root}
        style={{ border: 'none', boxShadow: 'none' }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
          <React.Fragment>
            <CardContent>
              <div className="total invest">
                <p className="main styling"> {props.collectedAmount}</p>
                <p className="details styling"> Comitted and reserved</p>
                <InvestLinearProgress {...props.goalPercentage} />
              </div>
              <Divider className="invest digits divider" />
              <div className="invest percentage">
                <p className="main styling">{props.goalPercentage} </p>
                <p className="details styling">Of minimum goals raised</p>
              </div>
              <Divider className="invest digits divider" />
              <div className="investers">
                <p className="main styling">{props.numberOfInversters}</p>
                <p className="details styling">Investers</p>
              </div>
              <Divider className="invest digits divider" />
              <div className="days left">
                <p className="main styling">{props.daysLeft}</p>
                <p className="details styling">Days Left to invest</p>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
              <div>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  sx={{
                    maxWidth: '30px',
                    maxHeight: '30px',
                    minWidth: '250px',
                    minHeight: '45px',
                    alignContent: 'center',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    marginTop: '10px',
                  }}
                >
                  Invest
                </Button>
              </div>
            </CardActions>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Box>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is the return of the grand parent :

```
return (
    <div className="main body">
      {' '}
      <div className="header main">
        <Header />
      </div>
      <section className="product main flex container">
        <bloc className="company details block">
          <div>
            <ProductInfo
              key={'product-' + id}
              id={id}
              header={header}
              title={title}
              description={description}
              category={category}
              img_logo={img_logo}
              tags={tags}
              mainImg={mainImg}
            />
          </div>
        </bloc>
        <bloc className="invest digits details block">
          <div className="product invest digits container">
            <ProductInvestDigits
              key={'product-' + id}
              id={id}
              collectedAmount={collectedAmount}
              numberOfInversters={numberOfInversters}
              daysLeft={daysLeft}
              goalPercentage={goalPercentage}
            />
          </div>
        </bloc>
      </section>
      <div className="footer">
        <div className="footer content">
          <Footer />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Disclaimer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You need to pass that prop into LinearDeterminate if you want access to it there.

Comment: That's because I have tried to do so but it does not work I will edit my code to show you how I am trying to do so

Comment: @ziwdig44bugs what are you trying to do by returning the prop inside the use effect?

Comment: @Jhonny I am trying to get a value goalPercentage from parent component and set it to value inside LinearProgress

Comment: are you passing the prop to the child? show the return of the parent element. The warning you show is just React saying did you mean to pass an empty depenedency array.

Comment: Thanks I will edit my return in the code

Comment: I am afraid if this is a silly question but if component A is parent of B which is Parent of C do I have to get the props from A directly or I should get it from B and if so how to syntax it?

Comment: in the "parent" component the LinearDeterminate is not being called, @ziwdig44bugs

Comment: Yes Jhonny what I have shared is the grand parent, this is my first tile with 3 level inheritance so I am trying to find out how it works

Comment: I have included the call in parent and grand parent now I can see that the value is propagating but it has wrong type it looks as it's an array:  
value : {0: "9", 1: "9"} I am seeding data from a json file : goalPercentage: '99',

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this warning from ESlint, you should put the ***props.goalPercentage*** inside your useEffect dependency.

Try this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function LinearDeterminate(props) {
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(props);

useEffect(() => {
  if(props.goalPercentage){
     setProgress(props.goalPercentage);
  }
}, [props.goalPercentage]);
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// your dependency

return (
  <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
    <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
   </Box>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but using this code I get this in react console :  
value : {}

Comment: or either you can use  useCallback hook by separating the setting of state

Comment: Okay so my error is that my prop is flowing from a grand parent and I did not got through the middle component

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help the last correction was to seed a number and not a string because the value of progress should be a number.